# RegEx: words with two letters repeated twice (eg. ABpoiuyAB, xnvXYlsdjsdXYmsd)

Tags: regex

I had two regex tasks to do today -- and I did one properly and failed with the other.
the first task was to find -- in a long, long text -- all the words beginning with "F" and ending with a vowel:

```
(\bf)\w*([euioay]\b)
```

and it worked perfectly.

the second one is way too difficult for a philology student ;-)
I have to find all the words with repeated at least twice two-letter sequences, for example:

- tatarak is TATArak, "TA" twice;
- brzozowski is brZOZOwski, "ZO" twice;
- loremipsrecdks is loREmipsREcdks, "RE" twice;

can I have some help please? thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see:

`(\w{2})` matches two letters (or digits/underscore, but let's ignore that) and captures them in group number 1. Then `\1` matches whatever was matched by that group. So

```
\b\w*(\w{2})\w*\1
```

is what you're looking for (you don't need `{2,}` because if three letters are repeated, two letters are also repeated. Not checking for more than two makes the regex much more efficient. You can stop matching after the `\1` backreference has succeeded).

Comment: thank you very much! it worked perfectly. now, if you're interested, such words occur 1499 times in Polish national epic poem "Pan Tadeusz". ;) amazing work, Tim -- and thanks for explanation! it was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern ought to do the trick

```
\b\w*?(\w{2})\w*?\1\w*?\b
```

- `\b` is a word boundry
- `\w*?` some number of letters (lazily)
- `(w{2})` exactly two letters, match and capture
- `\w*?` same as above
- `\1` the content of our two letter capture group
- `\w*?` same as above
- `\b` another word boundry

A quick test in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w*?(\\w{2})\\w*?\\1\\w*?\\b");
   final String string = "tatarak brzozowski loremipsrecdks a word that does not match";
   final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
   while(matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println("Found group " + matcher.group(1) + " in word " + matcher.group());
   }
}
```

Output

```
Found group ta in word tatarak
Found group zo in word brzozowski
Found group re in word loremipsrecdks
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that: `\b\w*?(\w{2})\w*?\1\w*\b`

Comment: I think you need `{2}` as the OP wants _two letter sequences repeated at least twice_.

Comment: Yeah, Tim Pietzcker already said that in his answer, but i edited mine now.